# Position of footer can't fixed

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/L9tqk/2/

i cant place my footer in correct place

```
<div id="logo"></div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="trans">
    <div id="data">
        <div id="left"> </div>
        <div id="right"> </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer"></div>


#footer {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 clear:both; 
}
```

when give

```
 bottom:0;
```

to #footer normal window it placed correctly, but when window size is changed, the footer position is not correct.

Comment: @Indian : i try that , but when window is resized all other content goes down but footer remains same.

Comment: final : http://jsfiddle.net/L9tqk/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `position:absolute;` from `#content #trans` and set `float` to it:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/L9tqk/6/)

```
#content #trans {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    border-radius:5px;
    color:Red;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Give `fixed` position to footer.

```
#footer{
    position:fixed;
}
```

[**Demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/L9tqk/5/)

OR:

Give `hidden` overflow to `#content #trans`.

Write:

```
#content #trans{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/L9tqk/7/)

Answer (score 1):

```
#content #trans {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    top:0px;  
    left:0px;  
    z-index:-1;
    border-radius:5px;
    color:Red;
   }
```

OR

```
#footer {
 position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  clear:both; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Final correct answer : http://jsfiddle.net/L9tqk/11/

```
 change `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;` and
    overflow: hidden; add in your `#content #trans`
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#footer {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  clear:both;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this Css position to relative and it works

```
#content #trans {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;  
    top:0px;  
    left:0px;  
    z-index:-1;
    border-radius:5px;
    color:Red;
   }
```

The updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/L9tqk/9/

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
   background:#999;
}

/* IE 6 */
* html #footer {
   position:absolute;
   top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}
```

This works for almost all web browsers. It remains fixed and all other contents will be behind it.